# How to use Powershell to modify System Variable in the user account?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to use powershell to change the path environment variable in my account for my company laptop.

I have tried to use [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path','mypath','User')
It will only set the path under User Variable

When I tried [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path','mypath','Machine')
I got an exception saying "Requested registry access is not allowed"

However, when I do start>Edit environment variables for your account> I can click and change the System Variable without issue.

Is there a way to do the same as above from powershell?

EDIT: there are 2 options from the start panel, "Edit environment variables for your account" and "Edit the system environment variables". I do not have the Admin right, so I can only access the first option which I can edit system variables from there.

Comment: Did you run PowerShell elevated? (eg. right-click -> "Run as Administrator...")

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am restricted from running powershell as administrator as my account does not have the admin right

Comment: Please contact a system administrator for assistance with modifying the system environment.  See output from `net.exe localgroup Administrators` for a list of accounts with the admin right -- assuming the local Administrators account hasn't been renamed.